# Sql management studio solution generation over TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, ssms

I'm writing some utility which performs following:

- creates structure for sql database
- creates solution + projects
- binds projects and solutions to TFS

I'm able to recreate .ssmssln, .ssmsqlproj, .vssscc, .vspscc files, and therefore create project with binding information. Also, I add and commit those files into TFS.

However, when I open the solution, SQL studio first asks for TFS server, and then complains that there is binding information for created project, but those aren't bound to TFS.

These problems can be probably corrected via .sqlsuo file, but it is binary, and I cannot create it. Is there any way how to create sqlsuo by hand (documentation for it), or to force projects to be bound so I don't have to bind them 'by hand'?

There will be a lot of created solutions, and the project should make it in 'run and work' way, I won't be commended, if there are other steps (few clicks) needed to perform to start working on project by DB developers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

devenv solution.sln /command file.tfsAddSolutionToSourceControl

This command binds the solution automatically without user interaction.

Comment: I'm using `Sql Management studio`, not `Visual studio`. `Visual studio` won't work with .ssmssln, and `Management Studio` doesnt recognize /command switch.

Comment: Oh yeah... I missed that I was just working with same thing but in VS 2008. Sorry.